# Bareword found where operator expected at Error in Perl script

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I have a script which is working fine in my local system (Cygwin in Windows 10).

But when I run same in Linux machine x86_64 GNU/Linux this shows below error:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at script.pl line 22, near "s/$regex/$1,/rg"
syntax error at script.pl line 22, near "s/$regex/$1,/rg"
Execution of script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $site_name    = $ARGV[0];
my $type_of_site = $ARGV[1];

chomp($site_name);
chomp($type_of_site);

my $var = `sh shell_script.sh $site_name $type_of_site`;
#The above shell script gives me following data in $var
#"Result data [[The Incident result is shown with Node and IP address. error.log warning.log http://10.0.0.11/home/node_data/2020-07-08_data.txt NODE IP NODE1 10.0.0.1 NODE2 10.0.0.2 NODE3 10.0.0.3 NODE4 10.0.0.4 NODE5 10.0.0.5 ]]";

print $var;

my $regex = qr/.*?(?P<Node>\w+)\s(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}) ?]?]?/mp;

my $result = $var =~ s/$regex/$1,/rg;

chop $result;

my @nodes_list = split /,/, $result;

print Dumper(\@nodes_list);
```

I am extracting node names from the shell script resultant data using regex. But why its showing the error when I run it in Linux environment?

Comment: 1) What line in the shown code is "line 22" in your actual script?  2) What are Perl versions on both systems?

Comment: 1) In line 22 I have `my $result = $var =~ s/$regex/$1,/rg;`. 2) In Linux I have `Perl v5.10.1` and windows `Perl v5.30.0`.

Comment: It works fine for me with perl 5.30 on Ubuntu. Can you try a  newer version of perl?

Comment: Also on v5.16 (CentOS7), no syntax errors with those regex expressions. I can't see what could be a _syntax_ error there?

Comment: (Btw, you don't use that name `Node` anywhere, like `$+{Node}` or such ... or do you?)

Comment: @zdim Nope. Im not using `Node` anywhere. The Node names are dynamic which would contain alphanumeric values.

Comment: @HåkonHægland right. In my Centos VM it works fine (It uses Perl v5.26.3). But I need to make it work on Perl v5.10.1.

Comment: You are using the `/mp` flags, but there are no anchors and you don't use the capture variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> my $result = $var =~ s/$regex/$1,/rg;
> ```

I don't have a perl version that old to test with, but the `r` modifier was added in 5.14. If you're using 5.10, I bet that's the cause of the error you're seeing - and it would explain why it's working fine on newer versions. Perl 5.10 was released in December 2007 - there's been a lot of work since then. I'd upgrade if you can, possibly using `perlbrew`.

But in the meantime... `r` returns a new copy of the transformed string, instead of altering the one the regular expression is bound to. So you might try something like

```
my $result = $var;
$result =~ s/$regex/$1,/g;
```

as a workaround.

Comment: Or, in a single line: `(my $result = $var) =~ s/$regex/$1,/g;`

Comment: Thanks @Shawn for the clarification.

Comment: A better solution would be to upgrade your `perl`. I shouldn't be using a 11-year old version of Perl! Cygwin provides 5.30.3

Answer (score 1):

The /r feature (Non-destructive substitution) you use in line 22

```
my $result = $var =~ s/$regex/$1,/rg;
```

was introduced in Perl 5.14.0: [perl5140delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html).